# How to enable zram swap in Android Build/kernel?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, android-kernel

How to enable zram as swap device in android linux kernel ? 
Is there any way create zram before init process ? kernelcmdline or kernel config.

As per [zram.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/zram.txt) no default way.

Comment: welcome. This is not a programming question.

Comment: stackoverflow allows to ask configuration/technology/coding/linux/development related questions.

Comment: better ask on super user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer (from [Android build zram](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/low-ram)):

1. Enable zram in kernel config as built in module.
2. Add the below line in your fstab file

   ```
   /dev/block/zram0 none swap defaults zramsize=size in bytes,swapprio=swap partition priority
   ```

   - zramsize is mandatory and indicates how much uncompressed memory you want the zram area to hold. Compression ratios in the 30-50% range are usually observed.
   - swapprio is optional and not needed if you don't have more than one swap area.
3. In init.rc add the following line:

   ```
   swapon_all /fstab.X
   ```